# Different Colors in primefaces bar chart

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

I would like to show primefaces barchart with different colors for each bar. the most close I got is like the image:

[image: sample]

I would like to have different color those bars, like green for "on time", yellow for "warning " and red for "overdue"

I tried to used  `model.setSeriesColors("58BA27,FFCC33,F74A4A,F52F2F,A30303");`
but if i do that each bar should be a new series, therefore I won't be able to show the labels as I wish (like the image), I got this..

[image]

last, how can I make it show  0,1,2,3 (integers) instead repeating 0_0_0_1_1_1_2_2_2 like the image 1 :/

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the problem by my own reading [this jplot documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/multipleBarColors.html), I'm posting here hope it can help someone...

for somehow, adding `extender` in the tag is not working for me, I have to put it via java code:

```
barModel.setSeriesColors("58BA27,FFCC33,F74A4A,F52F2F,A30303");
barModel.setExtender("chartExtender");
```

then javascript inside

```
<h:outputScript>
                        function chartExtender() {        
                         // this = chart widget instance        
                         // this.cfg = options      
                         this.cfg.seriesDefaults.rendererOptions.varyBarColor = true;
                        }
                        </h:outputScript>
```

and done!

[image]

Comment: Of course it is not working. PF removed the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new here, so I unfortunately cannot add a comment to your answer.
It worked for me too.
Some clarifications for other readers:

Be sure to put the `<h:outputScript>` under your `<p:chart...` like:

```
<p:chart type="bar" model="#{bean.someModel}">
     <h:outputScript>
         function chartExtender() {
             // this = chart widget instance
             // this.cfg = options
             this.cfg.seriesDefaults.rendererOptions.varyBarColor = true;
         }
     </h:outputScript>
 </p:chart>
```

The "extender" -Tag has been removed in Primefaces 5: 
[see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30644864/6324171)