# What is the alternative for the chart extender attribute in PrimeFaces 5.2 and newer

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, xhtml, jqplot

I'm using primefaces 5.2 latest version and tried for line chart, it's working fine.

Am trying to change the line chart axes color,background,border, etc. but extender attribute is not working in latest primefaces version.

My XHTML:

```
 <p:chart type="line" model="#{chartViewLine.lineModel1}" styleClass="legendpos" extender="chartExtender" style="height:300px; width:570px;"/>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function chartExtender() {        
    this.cfg.grid = {             
    background: 'transparent',
    gridLineColor: '#303030',
    drawBorder: false,
};
```

Is any alternative for 'extender' attribute OR my code have any wrong syntax?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should now set your extender from your model in your `chartViewLine` bean.

```
LineChartModel model = new LineChartModel();
model.setExtender("chartExtender");
```

---

Attribute `extender` has been removed in PrimeFaces 5.0 (see also list of `p:chart` attributes from [PrimeFaces 5.0 Documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_5_0.pdf))

Comment: Please file an issue in the PrimeFaces issue list. I personally still think this is an omission. You should be able to set the extender part from the view.

Comment: What about version 6.1 there is no extender.