# Showing decimal percentages in primefaces 5.1 pie chart

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using primefaces 5.1 and I am unable to display the percentages of the p:chart component as decimals. In the previous versions of primefaces this component was p:pieChart, and with that to display decimal one had to use the extender attributes of the pieChart. In the version 5.1 the p:chart component doesn't have this attribute.

Comment: So your BASIC question is NOT about decimal places, but about problems with the extender. Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644676/how-to-use-line-chart-extender-attribute-in-primefaces-5-2 (and also read the docs and look at the showcase)

Comment: So the duplicate has the right info? Great, next time please try to think what the core problem is that you have if you are sure you are thinking in the right direction (like in this case you did... extender...) Makes finding relevant questions easier (suggestions by stackoverflow e.g.)

Answer (score 0):

I finally added the javascript function below to my viewer.

```
function ext() {
   this.cfg.seriesDefaults.rendererOptions.dataLabelFormatString = '%.4s%%';
   this.cfg.seriesDefaults.rendererOptions.dataLabelThreshold = 0;
}
```

In the backend (controller) I parsed the string setExtender of the model to the name of my javascript function.

```
myPieChartModel.setExtender("ext");
```