# Modfiy bar width in primefaces chart

Tags: primefaces

How to modify bar width primefaces chart. Primefaces version is 6.1. Fewer versions have some solutions with extender attribute but 6.1 does not have extender attribute.

```
<p:chart id="basic1"   type="bar"  model="#{ucusYolcuBean.model}" style="width: 100%;" responsive="true" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use chart extender attribute in PrimeFaces 5.2 and newer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644676/how-to-use-chart-extender-attribute-in-primefaces-5-2-and-newer)

Comment: Sorry but that link not solved my question because primefaces version's are different.

Comment: So what problem did you have with what is described in that link...It is **the** solution for PF 5.2 and up...

Comment: PF 5.2 has extender attribute but 6.1 doesn't have

Comment: Thank you.I read pre solution carefully.Set extender in model it worked and I modified javascript function like that this.cfg.seriesDefaults.rendererOptions.barWidth = 60;